Live prices for tokens
just wanted to ask how do platforms like birdeye track live prices for tokens such as MEW with pools in e.g raydium/orca..
Trying to build some apis for self learning and was wondering if i could track on-chain instructions like Raydiums AddLiquidity and RemoveLiquidity
is that possible?

One of the ways might be to build Geyser plugin for collecting price changes of AMM accounts. The Solana Geyer Park is a good reference source: https://github.com/rpcpool/solana-geyser-park
